# Meaning of expression -(someClass *)methodName in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, instance-methods

What is meaning of the expression:

```
-(someClass *)someName;
```

How would you read/describe it in plain English?

Why do we put * inside brackets, and not before someName?

Do we allocate an object by this * or that just syntax?

Is it a case of "Casting"?

Is there a difference between Casting and returning a pointer?

Comment: why not even open Objective-c Wikipedia page before asking such a question?

Comment: That's a method signature. You should read it as you would `SomeClass* someName()` in C.

Comment: in objective C that expression would be found in an interface or header file (someFile.h), it is the interface declaration for a method you would later define in an implementation file (someFile.m)... the '-' minus sign denotes that it is an instance method to be called on an instance of an object. "(someClass *)" is a return type of the method and the asterisk '*' signifies this method will return a pointer to an object of 'someClass'.   finally 'someName' is the method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` identifies the method as an instance method, as opposed to the `+`, which identifies the method as a class method.

The return data type is the part inside the parenthesis.  You can't return an object by value, so you must return a pointer to an object, hence the `*` inside the parenthesis.  You are returning a `pointer` to `someClass`.

The beginning of the method name follows the parenthesis.

You would call this method `someName`, and it returns a pointer to an object of `someClass`, and it is an instance method.

If you were returning a primitive data type, the `*` would be unneeded because you can return primitive data types.  However, you could still return a pointer to a primitive data type, in which case you'd want the `*`.

For example:

```
-(int)someName; //returns an integer
-(int *)someOtherName; //returns a pointer to an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the Objective-C semantic for the return value of a method.

This:

```
-(someClass *)someName;
```

Means that calling someName will return a pointer to a someClass object.

For example:

```
someClass *myClass = self.someName;
```